# Why is my java app spending 30% of its time in young generation gc?

Tags: java, solr, garbage-collection

I was looking at the gc log file for our Solr installation, and I noticed its taking 30% of its time doing young generation gc. The log snippet below spans about a second, and the gc times add up to .34 seconds.

My question is: is this a problem, and if so what's causing it?

I am running jdk 1.6.0_24 on Linux

```
1004626.109: [GC 1004626.109: [ParNew: 74847K->5219K(76672K), 0.0838750 secs] 10831779K-
10762151K(11525824K), 0.0841790 secs] [Times: user=0.24 sys=0.00, real=0.09 secs] 
1004626.320: [GC 1004626.320: [ParNew: 73379K->5468K(76672K), 0.0527070 secs] 10830311K->10762874K(11525824K), 0.0529680 secs] [Times: user=0.20 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs] 
1004626.511: [GC 1004626.511: [ParNew: 73628K->4986K(76672K), 0.0591070 secs] 10831034K->10763002K(11525824K), 0.0593820 secs] [Times: user=0.20 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs] 
1004626.698: [GC 1004626.698: [ParNew: 73146K->5611K(76672K), 0.0523060 secs] 10831162K->10764169K(11525824K), 0.0525820 secs] [Times: user=0.21 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs] 
1004626.902: [GC 1004626.902: [ParNew: 73771K->6878K(76672K), 0.0653490 secs] 10832329K->10765868K(11525824K), 0.0656210 secs] [Times: user=0.22 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs]
```

Comment: Could the downvoter on the question justify its downvote ? There is no real point in downvoting if no reasons are given.

Comment: +1 to counter the IMHO undeserved downvote.

Comment: I'd say it is a problem if it takes away 30% of the time. As to what's causing it, well what else than a huge amount of short-lived object instantiation. Maybe you can find in your code where such a thing might be happening and try to redesign. The obvious places to look are massive loops (with many iterations). OTOH you might be just too low on heap.

Answer (score 4):

No, that's not a problem.  It means that your objects come and go - you create them in scope, use them, and then they're eligible for GC.  I don't think that's an indication that something's wrong.

The other extreme would be an issue: objects are created, age, and stick around too long.  That's where memory leaks and filled perm space happens.

Answer (score 2):

I think you *do* have a problem here.

I'm not an expert on reading GC logs, but I think it is saying that you have a 'young' space of 76672K, and a total heap size of 11525824K.  Furthermore, the total heap usage after each GC cycle is 10765868K ... and growing.  And it is (apparently) spending ~30% of its time garbage collecting.

My diagnosis is that your heap is nearly full, and you are spending a significant (and increasing) percentage of time garbage collection as a direct result.

My advice would be restart the application (short term), and look for memory leaks (long term).  If there are no memory leaks (i.e. your application is *using* all of that heap space) then you need to look for ways to reduce you application's memory usage.

Your application does seem to be generating a fair bit of garbage, but that is not necessarily a worry.  The HotSpot GCs can reclaim garbage pretty efficiently.  It is the amount of non-garbage that it has to deal with that causes performance issues.